# Angular2 Template Parse Errors EOF

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, typescript, angular, eof

In Angular2 (beta 13) I am attempting to display a list of data items retrieved from a database.  This part is working fine.

However, when I attempt to display these items (application names) in a html table, it does not work.  Strangely it does works when displaying this within a list.

**Error message**

```
EXCEPTION: Template parse errors:
Unexpected character "EOF" ("
        </table>
    </div>
</div[ERROR ->]"): ApplicationsComponent@13:5
```

**applications.html (CAUSES ERROR ABOVE)**

```
<div class="route-container route-container-margin-0 route-container-width-standard">
    <div class="route-container-padding-standard">
        <p>hello world</p>
        <table>
            <tbody>
                <tr *ngFor="#app of applications">
                    <td >
                        {{app.name}}
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

**applications.html (WORKS WITHOUT ERROR)**

```
<div class="route-container route-container-margin-0 route-container-width-standard">
    <div class="route-container-padding-standard">
        <p>hello world</p>
        <ul>
            <li *ngFor="#app of applications">
                {{app.name}}
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

**boot.ts**

```
///<reference path="./../node_modules/angular2/typings/browser.d.ts"/>
import {bootstrap}      from 'angular2/platform/browser';
import {ROUTER_PROVIDERS} from 'angular2/router';

import 'rxjs/Rx'; // kitchen sink

import {AppComponent} from './app.component';
import {HTTP_PROVIDERS}    from 'angular2/http';


// Bootstrap the application and reference the required directives
bootstrap(AppComponent, [ROUTER_PROVIDERS, HTTP_PROVIDERS]);
```

Thank you, Dan.

**UPDATE**

This is the data I am attempting to display (preferred to as app):

```
[{"applicationID":1,"name":"Applications","description":"Web applications","applicationRef":"Applications","status":true,"icon":"fa fa-th-large","iconColour":"ffffff","applicationColour":"ffffff","routerLink":"Applications","applicationFeatures":null}, .... more here]
```

This is my component (almost identical to the one that works).
The component that works is included on the page by way of tag e.g. , whereas the one that doesn't work is served via route traversal.

```
import {Component, OnInit} from 'angular2/core';

import {ApplicationVM} from '../ViewModels/Application.ViewModel';
import {ApplicationService}   from '../Services/application.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'ApplicationList',
    templateUrl: './app/Applications/Components/applications.html',
    providers: [ApplicationService]
})
export class ApplicationsComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor(private _applicationService: ApplicationService) { }

    errorMessage: string;
    applications: ApplicationVM[];

    ngOnInit() {
        console.log("INIT");
        this.getApplications();
    }

    listApps() {
        this.getApplications();
    }

    getApplications() {
        this._applicationService.getApplications()
            .subscribe(
            apps => this.applications = apps,
            error => this.errorMessage = <any>error);
    }

}
```

Comment: could you reproduce issue in [this plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/p79VIqJia3ALI4AUMYmA?p=preview)

Comment: `{{app?.name}}`???

Comment: app refers to #app.  name refers to the json data (I've added this above to my example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seemed to be a problem with browser link or live update in WebEssentials. Rebuilt PC and no problems (web essentials not installed and no other settings changed).

Full GitHub issue post:
https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/7983

Answer (score 2):

There could be some other issue because its working with `<table><tbody>` and `beta.13`

**[working demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/gA6H9ZH0FqLoGrozxAlj?p=preview)**

```
<div class="route-container route-container-margin-0 route-container-width-standard">
    <div class="route-container-padding-standard">
        <p>hello world</p>
        <table>
            <tbody>
                <tr *ngFor="#app of users">
                    <td >
                        {{app.firstName}}
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
 </div>
```

Update :

http://plnkr.co/edit/XhH1jjnxGfLMX1CuBgHo?p=preview

Comment: It works in one page but not the other i.e. displays as a table fine.  Initial page fine, then I browse to another page and it stops working.  I'm using a shared service, which seems to call fine on both pages (tried adapting your code to manually set data too to no avail).  There is some really sneaking going on - I don't usually get stuck for this long. It's almost identical component code to serve the page that works and the one that doesn't and no 404 either.

Comment: there must be some other issues.

Comment: Will do.  The page with an error works if the template html is entered into the multi-lined template within the component but not when it is in a separate html file. What could be going wrong there?

Comment: Ah ! please make sure every tag is written correctly in HTML file. I don't think there could be a separate file issue!

Comment: check my plunker. I have updated it with a separate html file.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108037/discussion-between-micronyks-and-danabdn).

Comment: Replaced my content with the already working content - works for <p>hello world<p>, doesn't work when I put a html table in there.